# Codeigniter routes not working when add (:any) in routes.php

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I'm just creating a new side section for my previous **CodeIgniter (3.1.2)** project.
**I just want to add the id number to the end of the URL and in routes**.php it looks like below,

`$route['single_receipt/(:any)'] = 'Accounting/single_receipt';`

all the fetched data from the database correctly loads with unique ids.
But **page design not loading correctly** and it looks like below image,

[image]

**How to fix this issue?** Hope someone give immediate help.
Thanks.